Enabling Tensorboard and reward logging for the Imitation framework
CHAI is UC Berkeley's framework for Imitation and Reward Learning algorithms (Inverse RL) > (https://github.com/HumanCompatibleAI/imitation)
I am unable to get the logging and Tensorboard enabled for the imitation library. Here is the logger utility - any help is appreciated.
https://imitation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_api/imitation.util.logger.html

I figured out the mechanism and posting it here for others who might be interested. It basically follows the StableBaselines (SB3) configure part, but then the implementation is different - SB3 uses model.set_logger(), whereas Imitation uses the custom_logger class member of the particular Imitation algorithm (in my case Behavioral cloning (BC):
from imitation.algorithms import bc
from imitation.util import logger as imit_logger

# Set new logger
log_path = '/irl_log/'
logger_irl = imit_logger.configure(log_path, ["stdout", "csv", "tensorboard"])

bc_trainer = bc.BC(
    observation_space=mt_venv.observation_space,
    action_space=mt_venv.action_space,
    demonstrations=transitions,
    rng=rng,
    device='cpu',
    custom_logger = logger_irl 
)

